# How to use the constant PIPE_BUF in C?

Tags: c, pipe

I need to use PIPE_BUF in my program which and for the size of PIPE_BUF I will be passing the parameters in command line argument.Can some one help me how to use it in the code?I have written the code but I am getting errors

I wrote the code

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE PIPE_BUF;
```

In the main()

```
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
PIPE_BUF=argv[4];
```

But it gives me error saying that error ']' passed before ';' token
and error in main()

Answer (score 4):

**Get rid of the semicolon**:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE PIPE_BUF;
                            ^
```

If you keep it, the code that reaches the compiler will be:

```
char buffer[4096;];
```

**Second, you can't asign to `PIPE_BUF`**. It's not an lvalue. It's like saying

```
4096 = argv[4];
```

Comment: It still gives error.....expected ']' before ';' token and in function main and the last error is lavalue required as left operand of assignment

Comment: then what to use to pass the buffer size in commnad line argument?I need to use PIPE_BUF....

Answer (score 2):

You must also include the file `limits.h`, which defines `PIPE_BUF`.

Comment: `#include <climits>` if using C++, `PIPE_BUF` will appear.

Comment: @user2205930 `#include <limits.h>` works in both C and C++.

Comment: xxx.h headers are discouraged for pure C++ code; they should only be used for writing C++ code that is also valid C code. The cxxx header equivalents conform to the C++ library conventions by providing their functionality in the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what problem you are trying to solve, perhaps you meant to do something like this, assuming you are using C as your programming language:

```
// Usage: myprog buf_size buf_data
int main()
{
  if (argc<3)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"Usage: myprog buf_size buf_data\n");
    return 1;
  }

  /* Get the buffer size */
  size_t pipe_buf_size=atoi(argv[1]);

  /* Allocate enough space to hold the buffer data */
  char *pipe_buf=(char *) malloc(pipe_buf_size);

  /* Copy the buffer data from the passed in argument */
  memcpy(pipe_buf,argv[2],pipe_buf_size);

  /* Do some work with it */
  ...

  /* Free the memory allocated for the buffer */
  free(pipe_buf);
}
```

Comment: but then dont I need to write #define buffersize pipe_buf and char buffer[buffersize]?